# Cómo hacer que me muestre el % que me falta por poner

Tags: java, formularios, apache-netbeans

os adjunto una captura de pantalla de un pequeño formulario en el cual hay que meter 3 notas y 3 %. Los % deben sumar el 100% al final. Lo que me me gustaría es poder informar de cuánto % te queda por poner. Este es muy sencillo porque solo lleva 3 datos, pero la idea es para poder "evaluar" bastantes indicadores, por eso para mí es importante que la persona que lo rellena sepa qué % puede poner. O sea, si en la primera celda pones 34% ya solo podrás poner entre las otras dos 66%. Si en la segunda pones otro 34% , que te avise o que directamente te ponga el número que solamente se puede poner(en este caso 32%). Eso querría que apareciera una label, pero no me doy cuenta de cómo hacerlo antes de pulsar el botón de Calcular.
Espero haberme explicado.
Un saludo y muchas gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que para ayudarte debes agregar lo que trataste por favor, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Restando porcentajes ejemplo :

tu variable porcentajeDisponible = 100 ;
ingresas 34 %
porcentajeDisponible -= 34 ;

ya en el boton Calcular podrias resetear porcentajeDisponible = 100
depende como lo estes planteando

jugando con los eventos del input deberias de poder hacerlo.